# why do we use categorical data-type and cat.codes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am a beginner, please explain what this code do precisely?

```py
DataFrame['X'] = pd.Categorical(DataFrame['X'])

DataFrame['X'] = DataFrame['X'].cat.codes
```

please explain what this code does precisely?

Comment: Primarily we use `categorical` values to save memory space. Suppose your data contains a column named `Gender` with 1000 rows which have only 2 types of values as `Male` and `Female`(both values are just repeated in rows). But for a computer there are 1000 unique values so it will treat every value as unique. To save memory we specify the similar set of values as category so that computer don't allocate memory every time it encounters that values, instead of that it will just assign a reference to the value.